# javascript ajax-call using callbacks vs passing in own functions

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, callback

I figured out that I can pass in functions which can be called in the ajax-call using jquery. But there are also callbackfunctions, which appended to the ajax-call itself. Now I would like to know, which way is the better way to work on the response-data:

Shoudl I write the code inside the (already existing) done-callback or in an own written callback function, which would be passed into the function, or maybe both?

The same question I have for the error-handling (fail, own fail-callback).
Following a few lines to explain bit better what I am talking about (I hope it is not too similar to an older question I had).

```
function retrieveAndDisplayWords(x){....}; // if there are words added
function workOnDataDelete(y){...};         // have round about 5 different functionalities to define

 myRPCcall(method, url, data, workOnData, failedCall){
    $.ajax( {
        type: method,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: data,
        url: url,
        dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(data, textStatus,jqXHR) {
           //work on data
            console.log("");
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
           //error-handling
            console.log("");
        });
  }


    // general ajax error handling function
    function failedCall( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        window.alert("AJAX call error occured");
        console.error( errorThrown );
    }
```

A call would look something like:

```
myRPCcall('GET', '/words/', null, retrieveAndDisplayWords, failedCall);
```

I passed two functions to the call and I appended two callbacks (done, failed).
As i understand callbacks 'done' and 'failed', those should contain what is happening to the responded data. As I also passed two functions for this purpose, I wonder, if this is redundant or if those two things are there for different purposes.

I assume following is not possible:
}).done(function(data, textStatus,jqXHR) {

```
  //work on data
  workOnData(); // the function cannot be seen in the done-callback, can it?
   console.log("");
}).
```

So as I need to work on the responded data in different ways I need to either pass the functions or have a huge if in the done-callback. Am I right? If yes - what is the better way?

Would I delegate it to the success-handler.
Can I pass the jqXHR to the functions somehow, or do they have access?

```
{
type: method,
contentType: "application/json",
data: data,
url: url,
dataType: "json",
success: workOnData, //new 
error: failedCall    //new
}
```

So basically: When and how to use passed in functions and what about the provided callbacks then?

Hope I described it clear enough, please let me know, if there is need to improve the post.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**success:**

**Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )**
A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

**error:**

**Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )**
A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn.

```
success: workOnData, //new 
error: failedCall    //new
```

Have your success and error  methods as follows.

```
function workOnData(data, textStatus, jqXHR ){ ... }
function failedCall(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )){ ... }
```

You can access jqXHR in your callback method by passing it as parameter.

For more details refer the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer - yep this is the documention... Therewith, do I still also use the 'done' and 'fail' callback-function, which are directly appendet to the $ajax-call? If I do an interface ("api") for the functions, should the "user" rather the part of the client write the function workOnData? (For example it could happen that once the returned data is listed on the scrren in a listform, and another time in a table,...).

Comment: Of course you can use **.done and .fail** callbaks too. `Note that success setting can accept an array of functions`. And you can define function body as per your requirement.

Comment: The question was not if I can, it was rather meant if it would make sense to use those in addition to the success and error ones. If I use both, wouldn't this be double then? The advantage of giving the functions as a parameter would be, that it could be individually, wouldn't it?

Comment: Hmm, it makes no sense if you are using both success and .done(). Both mean the same thing. .done() is triggered when your ajax status is success, so the .fail() when your ajax status is error.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So, as I apprehended, the exact same thing. Hm, ok. So I need to decide if the client should handle the success-function on its own, or if I am doing something. Whereas more general (it is about an API here) is, that user can decide what to do with those raw data. Thanks for your answers.